# Get value to display from another sql table

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 tables as attached image:

[image: Sql Tables]

In order to save space, i only store the ID.
In the gridview, i want to show the name based on the ID. 
I tried on inner join but only 1 parameter can be inner join. 
Any direction can i go? Please help.

Here is the code i tried:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProjectInfo] inner join [Employee] ON Employee.ID = ProjectInfo.ProjectInfo_Leader AND Employee.ID = ProjectInfo.ProjectInfo_CoLeader AND Employee.ID = ProjectInfo.ProjectInfo_Helper" 

SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProjectInfo] inner join [Employee] ON Employee.ID = ProjectInfo.ProjectInfo_Leader OR Employee.ID = ProjectInfo.ProjectInfo_CoLeader OR Employee.ID = ProjectInfo.ProjectInfo_Helper"
```

I am not familiar with SQL, thus i can only try and error...

Thanks.

Comment: Include the query that you have tried with inner join

Comment: Use Outer join please. Can you post your query?

Comment: Updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious solution.

```
select l.name leader,c.name [co-lider],h.name helper
from role r
left join people l on r.lider=l.id
left join people c on r.[co-lider]=c.id
left join people h on r.helper=h.id
```

Note: it is better to use `left join` in case some roles are not filled.

Comment: For gridview side, do i need to change the databind to new data(name)?

Comment: If you want to show new schema then you need to update GridView binding. Also I didn't include id's into the query. They may be usefull.